# SVN update using windows task scheduler not working

Tags: windows, svn, cron

I want to setup a windows cron job to update svn. I created a batch file with this step:

START TortoiseProc.exe /command:update /path:"C:\svn" /closeonend:0

and setup the task scheduler to run this daily. This svn requires a password which I want to enter each time rather than cache it. The batch file works as expected without any issues.

The task scheduler shows that the job was successfully executed. However, I don't get the GUI to enter the password, neither does the directory get updated. Also, when I tried to manually update the svn directory thereafter, it says that svn is locked.

1. Why is task scheduler reporting successful?
2. Why is svn getting locked?

Comment: Do you only have the one working copy in the C:\svn folder, and if so is that the root of the working copy? If not that's why it's failing - you've not actually specified a working copy in the /path option.

Comment: I've never had success getting any GUI program to run from task scheduler. I don't know if it's possible, to tell the truth.

Answer (score 0):

Task scheduler reports success because START seems to return exit code 0. START only starts an application and exits. It doesn't wait until the started application has exited. The task scheduler never sees the exit code of TortoiseProc this way.

You can do this with START WAIT. Enter `START /?` in a CMD for more information.
You can also do this with `CMD /K` itself. Enter `CMD /?` in a CMD for more information.

But I don't think you need START or CMD at all. You can either run TortoiseProc directly or call it via a batch script. In the batch script you can add more debugging like echos and redirected output in files to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Do **not** use TortoiseProc.exe for this task! Use Subversion command-line client (`svn.exe`). Read the docs:

> Remember that TortoiseSVN is a GUI client, and this automation guide
>   shows you how to make the TortoiseSVN dialogs appear to collect user
>   input. If you want to write a script which requires no input, you
>   should use the official Subversion command line client instead.